# Trying to work out a way to calculate the winner of a competition where each competition carries a different weighting

Tags: probability

I have been running a competition for my website but I am looking for a way to calculate this.

The question is:

Person A, B and C have all entered into a competition to win an iPhone. However, they have all entered into it multiple times.

Person A: 10 entries
Person B: 7 entries
Person C: 4 entries

Therefore, Person A will have a higher chance of winning that B and C.

What will be the best way to decide upon the winner as randomly as possible taking into account of the various weightings behind each Person.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a random number $n\in[1,21]$ with uniform distribution:

- If $n\leq10$, then person A wins
- Else if $n\leq17$, then person B wins
- Else (if $n\leq21$), then person C wins

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will end up with about 1000 different people - is there a way to incorporate this into excel? Such that if I work out the probabilities for each individual person, I can then run a rand() function which will then take into account of the probability which differs for each person?

Comment: @Tom: Assuming that you now understand the general method, publish this question (including a detailed description of that method) at http://stackoverflow.com. It most likely requires a VBA script, so make sure that you tag the question appropriately (Excel, VBA, etc).